# Unbind events by namespace backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Is it possible to unbind events by a namespace in backbone.js (like in jQuery)?

Example:

```
var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events)
dispatcher.on('hello.namespace', doSomething)
dispatcher.on('world.namespace', doSomethingElse)

dispatcher.off('.namespace')
```

It doesn't work that way. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/740).